# Correcting a data list in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

At some point, approximately 2,000 rows out of a total of 15,000 rows of data got messed up in Excel, and we only noticed it much later. We now have the correct data, and want to update only the incorrect 2,000 rows.

We have `Sheet 1` with 15000 rows and `Sheet 2` with 2000 rows, each with `Columns A` and `B`. In both Sheets, `Column B` will match, but `Column A` will only have approximately 2000 matches.

What I am looking to do is update `Column A` of `Sheet 1` with the correct data from `Column A` of `Sheet 2` based on matched data in `Column B` from both sheets.

Presumably, a `VLOOKUP` is the way to go, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share screenshots of each sheet and the desired result? Also, can you post the VLOOKUP that you've attempted?

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, consider adding it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: Thanks jsheeran, I wasn't sure it'd be acceptable to answer my own question like that but all done :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it!

Truth be told, I gave up on using a VLOOKUP and used INDEX & MATCH instead. The actual formula I used was:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH($E2,Sheet2!$C:$C,0)),D2)`

Since I was trying to match data in one column and fetch data from a different column in the results, this seemed simpler.

Apologies if I wasted anyone's time!